# Hausdorff dimension of the set of rational numbers within a certain interval?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, metric-spaces, rational-numbers, fractals

*Intro:* The Hausdorff dimension (also known as the Hausdorff–Besicovitch dimension) is an extended non-negative real number associated with any metric space. In general the Hausdorff dimension generalizes the notion of the dimension of a real vector space. That is, the Hausdorff dimension of an n-dimensional inner product space equals $n$. This means, for example, the Hausdorff dimension of a point is zero, the Hausdorff dimension of a line is one, and the Hausdorff dimension of the plane is two. *There are, however, many irregular sets that have noninteger Hausdorff dimension.* Many of the technical developments used to compute the Hausdorff dimension for highly irregular sets were obtained by Besicovitch.

Intuitively, consider the number $N(r)$ of balls of radius at most $r$ required to cover $X$ completely. When $r$ is small, $N(r)$ is large. For a "well-behaved" set $X$, the Hausdorff dimension is the unique number $d$ such that $N(r)$ grows as 1/rd as r approaches zero. More precise see [here>>>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension).

Having in background the real number line in mind, I am struggling, how to find:

*What is the Hausdorff dimension of the set of rational numbers within a certain interval?*

Comment: Hint: the rationals are countable.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis And what about transcendental numbers? Can we calculate H dimension for them?

Comment: You can choose a small enough cover that there are "gaps": see the answers here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2737868/does-certain-open-cover-for-rationals-numbers-in-0-1-cover-the-whole-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is provided in the link you give. The Hausdorff dimension of any countable set is $0$.

Comment: thanks got the point. I was confused by the parallels to Cantor set, which is uncountable.